# How to create collapsible/expandable rows in a table based on user action in lightning

Tags: lightning, datatable

I need to add collapsible/expandable rows based on an icon click. My code is effecting all the rows. But I need it for the specific rows where the user clicks on icons to expand or collapse. Below is the code:

Component:

```
<aura:component access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="dcrHistoryObject" type="Object" description="This is used to contain DataChangeRequestWrapper" access="public"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordID" type="String" description="Record Identifier for dcrHistoryObject" access="public"/>
    <aura:attribute name="dcrStatus" type="String" description="DCR status" access="public" default ="Open"/>
    <aura:attribute name="toggleName" type="String" description="Toggle Name" access="public" default ="utility:chevrondown"/>
    <aura:attribute name="noOfChildRows" type="Integer" description="Number of Child Rows" access="public"/>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered" role="treegrid" aria-owns="tree0-node0 tree0-node1 tree0-node2 tree0-node3" 
        aria-readonly="true">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                <th class="" scope="col">
                  <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center">
                      <div class="slds-truncate slds-m-left_medium" title="{!!$Label.c.DCR_HistoryField}">{!$Label.c.DCR_HistoryField}</div>
                  </div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!$Label.c.DCR_HistoryOldValue}">{!$Label.c.DCR_HistoryOldValue}</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!$Label.c.DCR_HistoryNewValue}">{!$Label.c.DCR_HistoryNewValue}</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!$Label.c.DCR_HistoryModifiedBy}">{!$Label.c.DCR_HistoryModifiedBy}</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                  <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!$Label.c.DCR_HistoryModifiedDate}">{!$Label.c.DCR_HistoryModifiedDate}</div>
                </th>                            
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.dcrHistoryObject}" var="recordHistory" indexVar="recIndex">
                <aura:iteration items="{!recordHistory.fieldHistoryList}" var="historySobject" indexVar="historyIndex" end = "{!v.noOfChildRows}">  
                <tr>
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!historyIndex== 0}">
                        <th data-label="Account Name" scope="row" rowspan="{!recordHistory.fieldHistoryList.length}" 
                            style="vertical-align: top;" class ="slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-6">
                            <span style="display:flex;">
                                <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="{!v.toggleName}" variant="bare" size="x-small" alternativeText="Toggle" class="slds-m-right_x-small slds-shrink-none slds-table_tree__toggle" onclick = "{!c.toggleIcon}"/>
                                <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!recordHistory.keyFieldLabel}">
                                    {!recordHistory.keyFieldLabel}
                                </div>
                `            </span>
                        </th>
                    </aura:if>

                    <td role="gridcell" class="slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-6">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!or(equals(historySobject.fieldType, 'DATE'), equals(historySobject.fieldType, 'DATETIME'))}">
                            <div class="slds-grid">
                              <div>
                                <lightning:input type="radio" name="{!add(add(recIndex,'-'), v.recordID)}" 
                                 value="{!historySobject.oldValue}"  onchange="{!c.selectHistoryValue}" 
                                 disabled="{!v.dcrStatus =='Closed'}"
                                 /> 
                              </div>
                              <div class="dcr-radio-label">
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!equals(historySobject.fieldType, 'DATETIME')}">
                                    <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!historySobject.oldValue}"
                                    year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric"  hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit"/> 
                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                        <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!historySobject.oldValue}"/>                           
                                    </aura:set>                                         
                                </aura:if>                  
                              </div>    
                            </div>   

                            <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <lightning:input type="radio" label="{!historySobject.oldLabel}" name="{!add(add(recIndex,'-'), v.recordID)}" value="{!historySobject.oldValue}"  onchange="{!c.selectHistoryValue}" 
                                disabled="{!or( equals(v.dcrStatus,'Closed')
                                                , and(
                                                    equals(historySobject.oldValue, NULL)
                                                    , equals(historySobject.fieldType, 'BOOLEAN')
                                                )
                                            )}"/> 
                            </aura:set>                         
                        </aura:if>                  
                    </td>
                    <td role="gridcell" class="slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-6">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!or(equals(historySobject.fieldType, 'DATE'), equals(historySobject.fieldType, 'DATETIME'))}">
                            <div class="slds-grid">
                              <div>
                                <lightning:input type="radio" name="{!add(add(recIndex,'-'), v.recordID)}" 
                                 value="{!historySobject.newValue}"  onchange="{!c.selectHistoryValue}" 
                                 disabled="{!v.dcrStatus =='Closed'}" checked="true"
                                 /> 
                              </div>
                              <div class="dcr-radio-label">
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!equals(historySobject.fieldType, 'DATETIME')}">
                                    <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!historySobject.newValue}"
                                    year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric"  hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit"/> 
                                    <aura:set attribute="else">
                                        <lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!historySobject.newValue}"/>                           
                                    </aura:set>                                         
                                </aura:if>                  
                              </div>    
                            </div>   

                            <aura:set attribute="else">
                                <lightning:input type="radio" label="{!historySobject.newLabel}" name="{!add(add(recIndex,'-'), v.recordID)}" value="{!historySobject.newValue}" onchange="{!c.selectHistoryValue}" checked="true" disabled="{!v.dcrStatus =='Closed'}"/> 
                            </aura:set>                         
                        </aura:if>                  
                    </td>

                    <td role="gridcell" class="slds-wrap slds-size_1-of-6">
                        <div class="slds-truncate">{!historySobject.createdBy} </div>
                    </td>
                    <td role="gridcell" class="slds-wrap slds-size_2-of-6">
                        {!historySobject.formattedCreatedDate}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </aura:iteration> 
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

Controller js:

```
({
    selectHistoryValue : function(component, event, helper) { 
        var source = event.getSource();
        // selected value of a row
        var selectedValue = source.get('v.value');
        // Get name property of a row
        var name = source.get('v.name');
        // Get row index
        var rowIndex = name.split("-")[0];

        var recordHistory = component.get('v.dcrHistoryObject');
        // set selectedValue for a specific row
        if(recordHistory !=null && recordHistory.length>0 && rowIndex < recordHistory.length){
            recordHistory[rowIndex].value = selectedValue;  
        }
        component.set('v.dcrHistoryObject', recordHistory);
    },

    toggleIcon : function(component, event, helper) { 
        var toggleName =  component.get('v.toggleName');
        if(toggleName == "utility:chevrondown"){
            component.set('v.toggleName',"utility:chevronright");
            component.set('v.noOfChildRows',"1");
        }
        else{
            component.set('v.toggleName',"utility:chevrondown");
            component.set('v.noOfChildRows','v.historyIndex');
        }
    },
     makeRowCompact: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.compact", true);
    },

    makeRowDetailed: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.compact", false);
    },
})
```

Comment: have you considered using the [lightning:accordion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_accordion.htm) component?

Comment: accordion collapses other sections when I expand one. My requirement is to collapse / expand as many rows as the user wants.

Comment: [Dynamically Showing or Hiding Markup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_show_hide_markup.htm) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one Boolean value per row. Typically, the easy way to do this it to include it directly in the data, or as a related array. Here's a very simple copy-paste example for you.

---

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Object[]" default="[]" />

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item" indexVar="itemIndex">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="12">

                <h1>
                    <lightning:buttonIcon value="{!itemIndex}" onclick="{!c.toggle}" iconName="{!item.expanded?'utility:chevrondown':'utility:chevronright'}" />
                    {!item.title}
                </h1>
                <aura:if isTrue="{!item.expanded}">
                    <div>
                        Extra content would be shown here.
                    </div>
                </aura:if>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:layout>
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    init: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.items", [
            { expanded: false, title: "Row 1" },
            { expanded: false, title: "Row 2" },
            { expanded: false, title: "Row 3" }
        ]);
    },
    toggle: function(component, event, helper) {
        var items = component.get("v.items"), index = event.getSource().get("v.value");
        items[index].expanded = !items[index].expanded;
        component.set("v.items", items);
    }
})
```

---

Notice here how I set the Boolean value *for the row I want to toggle*. Doing this allows any number of rows to be collapsed/expanded as I desire.

Comment: This approach perfectly worked for my requirement. Thank you so much for the help.